# Bizarre polygons from a shapefile

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply a shapefile to a ggmaps map, but it's giving me really weird results.  The shapefile in question is the "Statistical Local Area" (groups similar to postcode) shapefile from the Australian Bureau of Statistics available [here](http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1259.0.30.001July%202011?OpenDocument).

[image: SLA Shapefile applied at zoom level 4]

Normally I might think that it's a problem of cut off edge points, but I'm hitting it even at zoom level 1 (in fact it looks even worse):
[image: SLA Shapefile applied at zoom level 1]

Here's some code I used to produce the charts above:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)

slas <- readOGR(dsn="SLA",layer="SLA11aAust")

aus4 <- get_map("Australia",zoom=4)
ggmap(aus4)

ggmap(aus4)+
  geom_polygon(data=slas, aes(x=long,y=lat))

aus1 <- get_map("Australia",zoom=1)
ggmap(aus1)

ggmap(aus1)+
  geom_polygon(data=slas, aes(x=long,y=lat))
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is the shapefile incorrectly configured somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just need to (optionally) `fortify` the variable `slas`, don't forget to `group` and make the boundaries visible with a color:

```
slas <- fortify(slas, region = "SLA_CODE11")
ggmap(aus4) + 
  geom_polygon(data = slas2, color = "white", aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))
```

[image]

Comment: You're right, that looks much better.  What does `fortify` do?  The documentation now just says "Go use the `broom` package instead", which... isn't helpful.

Comment: `fortify` converts `slas` from a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` to a regular `data.frame`. Strictly-speaking it's not necessary; the key thing missing was the `group = group` parameter.