# ggplot2 map produces zigzag fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

Not sure what it going on - this was all working fine until one plot threw this at me. I managed to create this (seemingly) out of the blue.

My code can be found here: https://github.com/popovs/400m-cartograms

Result: [image: whacky map plot]

Comment: This usually occurs because you did not use `group = group` in `geom_polygon`. [See this similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577160/bizarre-polygons-from-a-shapefile).

Comment: in any case, this is a somehow beautifully warped world map. :)

Comment: I've updated the question with my more detailed code and data, and an unfortunately slightly less beautifully warped map XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to include this before feeding your data into ggplot:

```
library(dplyr)

map_data_1950 <- arrange(map_data_1950, order)
```

When you performed `merge()` on your map data, the order of coordinates in some countries got mixed up. Reordering them should resolve the issue.

```
# Illustration
p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = map_data_1950,
               aes(fill = Catch, x = long, y= lat, group = group)) +
  ggtitle("Without reordering")

p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = arrange(map_data_1950, order),
               aes(fill = Catch, x = long, y= lat, group = group)) +
  ggtitle("With reordering")

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

[image: comparison]

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to group the regions:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = map_data("world"), 
               aes(long, lat, group = group))
```

Comment: Agh, stupid mistake on my part. Thank you. 
However... on my slightly more complicated dataset, I'm getting this: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'group' not found`

Comment: Perhaps that dataset does not contain a column named `group`, in which case look for another column that identifies regions. Or perhaps you didn't wrap it inside `aes()` ?

Comment: I've edited the question to include my original code & data - I think I simplified it too much in my example. Perhaps there's something going wrong in my data join or some other way I'm plotting it.